# Special characters through my PC keyboard don't work in Genymotion emulator

Tags: keyboard, android-emulator, genymotion

I use Genymotion emulator version 2.2 to run android version 4.3. It is on Ubuntu 14.04. Typing with my keyboard works, but not for special non-asci characters like  ščřžáíéúů. Pasting them works. I do not have any idea where to look in order to try to fix the problem, any suggestions?

Comment: I am not the only one wiht this problem (and there is no solution for 4.3 just yet): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/genymotion-users/SlIG6c_-Gs0